# Strange bash script behaviour

Tags: bash, sudo

I have two bash scripts, which are binary identical, have the same permissions, are unique on my drive and are not found in `sudoers`. Still one passes the uid test for root, the other one not. If I call the first one with `./` in the bin folder, it behaves like the second.

The script (sync-samuel):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "[$0]"
whoami

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root"
    exit 1
fi

id -u
exit
```

The output:

```
samuel@xeon:~$ sync-samuel
[sudo] password for samuel: 
[/home/samuel/bin/sync-samuel]
root
0
samuel@xeon:~$ sync-samuel2
[/home/samuel/bin/sync-samuel2]
samuel
This script must be run as root
samuel@xeon:~$ cd bin
samuel@xeon:~/bin$ ./sync-samuel
[./sync-samuel]
samuel
This script must be run as root
```

The permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samuel samuel  435 Feb  1 22:36 sync-samuel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samuel samuel  435 Feb  1 22:37 sync-samuel2
```

File:

```
samuel@xeon:~/bin$ file sync-samuel
sync-samuel: a /usr/bin/env bash script, ASCII text executable
samuel@xeon:~/bin$ file sync-samuel2
sync-samuel2: a /usr/bin/env bash script, ASCII text executable
```

Does anyone know, what triggers this behaviour or how I can view extended properties of these two files?
I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 LTS w/ bash 4.3.11(1)-release.

Edit: G-Man ist the man! The first one is also an alias:

```
samuel@xeon:~/bin$ type sync-samuel2
sync-samuel2 is hashed (/home/samuel/bin/sync-samuel2)
samuel@xeon:~/bin$ type sync-samuel
sync-samuel is aliased to `sudo /home/samuel/bin/sync-samuel'
```

Comment: Do you have any clue how/why `sync-samuel` is giving you a `sudo` dialog when it doesn't call `sudo`?  Type `type sync-samuel` and `type sync-samuel2` and see whether that helps you.  Please do not post clarifying information in comments; if you have additional information to provide, [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  This test is common and is working properly.  Your output tells me that samuel is not in your sudo'ers file.  The question is why does whoami return 0 in the first case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output shows that `sync-samuel` issues a `sudo` prompt,
even though you run it without `sudo`
and the script itself doesn’t invoke `sudo`. 
This doesn’t make any sense. 
It looks like, when you type `sync-samuel`,
you’re running something other than
the `sync-samuel` script that you show in the question.

It is possible that `sync-samuel` is actually
an alias for `sudo sync-samuel` or something similar. 
Another possibility is that you have another copy of `sync-samuel`
in another directory, and your shell is finding (and running) it
rather than the copy you’re looking at. 
To diagnose this, issue the following command:

```
type sync-samuel sync-samuel2
```

`type` is a built-in command
that shows how the shell interprets each command. 
If you get substantially different responses for the two files
(e.g., `sync-samuel` is an alias and `sync-samuel2` is not),
you will know how to proceed to cause them to be handled the same
(e.g., define an alias for `sync-samuel2`, too).

Comment: I think the path the script prints out rules out another script with the same name. The alias (or a shell function) seems a plausible reason.

Comment: Good point — I overlooked that.